# Cpanel/WHM solution in microsoft windows server

Tags: cpanel, whm, web-farm

Does Microsoft provide a web hosting solution similar to Cpanel/Whm in linux?
what i really want is to build a powerful server where i give my org developer a cpanel-like tool to manage their sites instead of giving them vps or direct access to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck [Enkompass by cPanel](http://www.cpanel.net/windows/overview.html).

Answer (score 1):

Enkompass is now free
http://www.cpanel.net/2011/10/cpanel-to-offer-enkompass-for-free.html

For Linux servers cPanel is the best but on windows Plesk is the best option http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/